# Trimming linux log files

Tags: linux, logging

It seems like a trivial issue, but I did not find a solution.
I have a number of log files in a php installation on Debian/Linux that tend to grow quite a bit and I would like to trim nightly to the last 500 lines or so.
How do I do it, possibly in shell and applying a command to *log?

Answer (score 3):

For this, I would suggest to use `logrotate` with a configuration to your liking instead of programming your own script.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more elegant way to do this programmatically, but it is possible to use `tail` and a for-loop for this:

```
for file in *.log; do
    tail -500 "$file" > "$file.tmp"
    mv -- "$file.tmp" "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save history of older files, you should check out [logrotate](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/).

Otherwise, this can be done trivially with the command line:

```
LOGS="/var/log"
MAX_LINES=500

find "$LOGS" -type f -name '*.log' -print0 | while read -d '' file; do
  tmp=$(mktemp)
  tail -n $MAX_LINES $file > $tmp
  mv $tmp $file      
done
```